# Buscar registro no mongo e fazer update

Tags: mongodb

Preciso de uma ajuda para fazer um `update` em um registro específico. Abaixo está o documento que quero alterar.

```
{  
  "_id":"ddc07497-003d-3dff-8f82-24b9b980a568",
  "date":"2018-04-19T17:14:29.699Z",
  "messages":[  
     {  
        "intents":[  

        ],
        "entities":[  

        ],
        "input":{  
           "text":"attachments",
           "date":"2018-04-19T17:14:44.699Z",
           "user":{  

           },
           "payload":{  
              "watsonOnly":"attachments"
           },
           "files":[  
              {  
                 "name":"Screen Shot 2018-04-05 at 09.00.15.png",
                 "url":"http://localhost:3000//uploads/5a8704792db4cf0a896ca668/files/35bd963d-4477-4817-8d29-3b234202978a.png"
              }
           ]
        },
        "output":{  
           "text":[  
              "Você pode reformular sua afirmação? Eu não estou entendendo."
           ],
           "nodes_visited":[  
              "Em outros casos"
           ],
           "log_messages":[  

           ],
           "date":"2018-04-19T17:14:45.125Z",
           "user":{  
              "id":"a079d4be-5190-ebe6-c55f-623aab50a665",
              "name":"Robo do xande",
              "avatar":"http://localhost:3000/uploads/5a8704792db4cf0a896ca668/avatar/e332048b-e7dd-45be-a6df-59b4a57545f8.jpeg"
           }
        }
     }
  ],
  "sizeOfmessages":2}
```

Preciso encontrar o documento com o mesmo `_id` e depois com a mesma `url` que esta dentro de `input.files`, e ao encontrar, fazer um update e setar a `url` como vazia.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Olá! O que você já tentou?

Comment: `$match: { 
                        "_id":params._id, 
                        $or: [{"messages.input.files.url": params.url},{messages.output.files.url": params.url }] 
                    },
                    {
                        $set: { 
                            "messages.0.input.$.files.url": "",
                            "messages.0.output.$.files.url": "",
                        }
                    }
                });`